# How can we insert multiple titles on UInavigationBar in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in iOS and in my project i need to insert "titles" at "left side center" and "right side center" on UInavigationBar as like below image please help me how should i do below my requirement

[image]

Comment: Insert two labels in navigation bar instead of using default title

Comment: programatically i need to insert two labels and moreever both are fixed at center as like below image can you please explain me with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below code and try :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width/2, 44)];
    lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl1.text = @"Dashboard";
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:lbl1];

    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width/2, 0, frame.size.width/2, 44)];
    lbl2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl2.text = @"Profile";
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:lbl2];
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. You certainly shouldn't be basing the frames on the screen size. And what happens when the user changes device orientation? Or what about if the navbar has a back button or other buttons? The other answer is much better by using the `titleView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the `titleView` of navigation bar. Read the [official documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView).

As per your question, I tried the below working code:-

```
-(UIView *)getTitleView
{
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIView *viewTitle = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];

    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width/2, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
    lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:130/255.0f green:13/255.0f blue:23/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    lbl1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [lbl1 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    lbl1.text = @"Dashboard";
    [viewTitle addSubview:lbl1];

    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width/2, 0, frame.size.width/2, viewTitle.frame.size.height)];
    lbl2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:130/255.0f green:13/255.0f blue:23/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    [lbl2 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    lbl2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl2.text = @"Profile";
    [viewTitle addSubview:lbl2];


    return viewTitle;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [self getTitleView];
}
```

I divide the code in separate method to follow [modular approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming). For any part of code, which is of separate task, write that piece of code in different method. This will lead to more readability.