# how to set UILabels on navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I have try to set `UILabels` on navigationbar.In potrait mode it fit correct but when we rotate the landscape mode it does n't fit correctly.Please help me any one.

My code is below:

```
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

 UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width/2, 44)];
        lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        lbl1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lbl1.text = @"Dashboard";     

 UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width/2, 0, frame.size.width/2, 44)];
    lbl2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl2.text = @"Profile";

 UIView *customView  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];   
    [customView addSubview:lbl1];
    [customView addSubview:lbl2];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = customView;
```

[image]

Comment: better adding as a subview use self.navigationItem.titleView = yourview;

Comment: As this probably refers to your previous question, I would like to refer you to this answer on the same - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33623327/3769927

Comment: Better way to add title view. But if you want solution of your problem you have to set autoresizingMask property of both labels, like lbl1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
UIView *customView  = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[customView addSubview:lbl1];
[customView addSubview:lbl2];
self.navigationItem.titleView = customView;
```

Comment: Why is `customLabel` a `UILabel`? It should be a `UIView`. And its frame should not be the same as the frame of the navigation bar. If anything, it should match the bounds of the navigation bar, but not the frame.

Comment: Hi Jamil i tried your code but it does n't fie landscape mode.see belo link   file:///Users/Adamas/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-10%20at%201.02.23%20PM.png

Comment: you provided the link is you local desktop link. i can't see this link

Comment: see jamil i have edited my code in landscope mode it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Working in landscape and portrait mode so try this code

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation ]== UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Lanscapse");
        [self ViewFrameSet];
    }
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
    {
        NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationPortrait");
        [self ViewFrameSet];
    }
}
-(void)ViewFrameSet
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44)];
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2, 44)];
    label.text = @"Dashboard";
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [view addSubview:label];
    
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2, 44)];
    label1.text = @"Profile";
    label1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [view addSubview:label1];
    
    self.navigationItem.titleView = view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should get the navigationBar's size.As you image,the height is the problem,isn't fit the navigationBar.

When you change to landScapeMode,you should  reset you label's frame as landScapeMode's navagationBar's height.

Hope to help you.